# mapping repeating ID's for an email

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with columns ID MAIL (20 millions):

```
000000@0000.com 0xE618EF6B90AG
000000@0000.com 0xE618EF6B90AF
00000@00000.com 0xE618EFBCC83D
00000@00000.com 0xE618EFBCC83C
@000000000 0xE618F02C223E432CEA
00000@0000.com 0x01010492A
0000@00000.com 0x52107A
@ 0xE618F032F829432CE04343307C570906A
00000@0000.com 0xE618F032F829432CEB
000000@000.com 0xE618F032FE7B432CEC
000000@000.com 0xE618F032FE7B432CED
@hotmail.com 0x41970588
@ 0x52087617
```

I need to map ID's registered to an email, so we can find what ID's have registered on a given mail. The email may have several ID's registered on it.
Here is the function i made, but it turns out that i need to exclude mostly non-valid emails like `@.com` `@` etc.

In the first version of script it works almost perfectly with a little thing, my parser breaks down if the email has a `space` somewhere in between symbols

So i added a regexp to check the email value but i get the error i don't know how to handle:

```
import re

def duplicates(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    query = (line.replace('\n','') for line in lines)
    split_query = (line.split(' ') for line in query)

    result_mail = {}
    for line in split_query:
         #added if statement to validate email, remove to check w/o
         if re.match(r"[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+", line[0]):
            if line[0] not in result_mail:
                 result_mail[line[0]] = []
         result_mail[line[0]].append(line[1])

    for mail, ids in result_mail.iteritems():
        if len(ids) > 1:
            with open('MAIL_ids.txt', 'a') as r_mail:
                r_mail.write(str(mail) + '\n')
                r_mail.write(str(ids) + '\n')   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    duplicates(filename)
```

After running the script i get the error about `KeyError ''`, why is this happening ?

```
File ".\dup_1.2.py", line 44, in <module>
    duplicates(filename)
File ".\dup_1.2.py", line 32, in duplicates
    result_mail[line[0]].append(line[1])
KeyError: ''
```

I also would like to rewrite the part where i add keys and values to dictionary. I'd like to use a generator `defaultdict()` smth like:

```
result_mail = defaultdict(list)
for line in lines:
    if line[0] not in result_mail:
        result_mail[line[0]].append(line[1])
```

Comment: Alright! Good luck! (I don't see any question here)

Comment: @EmilVikström, okay the question is, how to get rid of KeyError?

Comment: Should this line be indented by one more level, to be inside the `if re.match` block? Also, you might want to use `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: @tobias_k thanks! i've just founded it a minute ago as well, as concerns defaultdict, i assume the import has been already done, thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just put the line `result_mail[line[0]].append(line[1])` at the wrong level of indentation, so it is executed even when the `if re.match` condition does not apply.

Also, you might want to use `collections.defaultdict` to get rid of that `if line[0] not in result_mail` check.

```
result_mail = collections.defaultdict(list)
for (id_, mail) in split_query:
    if re.match(r"[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+", id_):
        result_mail[id_].append(mail)
```